# AdMobをiOSのアプリに実装するための.xcworkspaceファイルが生成されないことについてご教示ください

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

Google AdMobをiOSのアプリに実装するためにターミナルから.xcworkspaceとPodfile.lockを作ろうとしましたができませんでした。

ターミナルのエラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
[!] Unable to determine the platform for the `（アプリ名）` target.
```

以下のことをした時のエラーです。
ターミナルにおいて、
1.cd プロジェクトまでのパス
2.pod init　ファイルを作成
3.pod initのtarget '(プロジェクト名)' do〜endの間に
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'を追加
4. pod install
以上をすると
[!] Unable to determine the platform for the アプリ名 target.
というエラーが出ます。

４つのアプリを所有しておりますが、２つは上記のやり方でうまくできましたが、残りの二つができません。（違いといえはStoreKidがあること？）

#### 試したこと1

ターミナルでpod deintegrateコマンドを実行して既存のCocoaPods設定をリセット。
Podfileを再度編集し、上記の手順と同じようにpod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'を追加。
ターミナルでpod installコマンドを実行して、CocoaPodsを再インストール。

#### 試したこと2

ターミナルにて
1.vim ~/.zshrc
2.rbenv にパスを通す
[[ -d ~/.rbenv ]] &&
export PATH=${HOME}/.rbenv/bin:${PATH} &&
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

他に調べたところ「これらの手順を試しても解決しない場合、Xcodeの設定やプロジェクトの設定に問題があるかもしれません。」とのことでしたが、どうすればいいかわかりませんでした。何卒ご教示くださいますようよろしくお願いいたします。

##### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

```
% which ruby
/Users/name/.rbenv/shims/ruby

% ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin23]

% pod --version
1.14.3
```

AdMob ではこれらのアプリはすべて「準備完了」状態です。

MacBook Pro (M2チップ)

Xcode 15.0.1

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/v3h2tblgcgom1n) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: マルチポストとご指摘ありがとうございます。そのようなことがあるとは存じ上げまず失礼いたしました。両サイトとも誠実に対処いたしますので、何卒ご教示くださると幸いです。またその他、不備がありましたらなんでもご指摘ください。申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: 『ポッドファイルの 2 行目のコメントを外して (# を削除して) みてください。プラットフォーム宣言がコメントアウトされているため機能していないと思います』https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327864/pod-install-error-unable-to-determine-the-platform-for-the-adewolefarmapこちらのサイトをご紹介いただき解決できました。重ね重ねマルチポストの件、失礼いたしました。また、cubick♦様におかれましては、無知な私にマルチポストの件や丁寧な投稿修正いただき誠にありがとうございました。また、そのほか決にご協力いただきましたみなさま誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: cubick♦様　手直ししていただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

teratailでも同じ質問をしており、そちらのコメント欄で言及のあった記事を参考に対応しました。
具体的には、Podfile の最初にある `# platform :ios` の行の `#` を消す。

**参考:**
[pod install error>>> [!] Unable to determine the platform for the `AdewoleFarmApp` target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74327864/2322778)